# How to draw vertical lines between columns of a list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview, divider, multiple-columns

Here I am creating an android application consists of multicolumn list view.By this multicolumn list view I want to separate data of each column by drawing a vertical lines between them. Can any one tell me how to draw the vertical lines between the list view columns.Thanks in advance

This is my list view layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.developer.milanandroid.AC_fuse_ckt" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pager_sliding_tab_strip"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_s.no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="sno"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_test_point_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:text="Pointname"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Range"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:text="Range"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Measurement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:text="Result"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View android:id="@+id/view_1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="#BDBDBD"
          android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_bc_fuse_ckt_tests"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="20dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `GridView` for this instead of `ListView`

Comment: Can you provide the layout file that contains the `ListView`s? Are you using multiple `ListView`s or are you separating the columns within each `ListItem`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply dude.But,here I want to use list view is it possible with the list view @SandeepSingh

Comment: @dEePU Yes, But can you post your layout

Comment: I posted my layout please check it out dude @SandeepSingh

Comment: I posted my layout please check it out dude @AlexWalterbos

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: But i want it on List view dude @Sandeep Singh

Comment: This the adapter layout

Comment: ListView only contains rows

Comment: I know that dude but here I need vertical lines between columns of list view @Sandeep Singh

Answer (score 1):

One trick for list that do not have too many columns, each column having a fixed size, is to simply divide your list item layout using the same dimensions you use to divide the headers.

Then, between each column in the list row, you can

- add a `View` of 1px width and the desired separator color as background color
- or put a background image on each cell that has a border on its left or right side, probably using a 9-patch
- or let `LinearLayout` do the job for you!

Some details on the third solution :
Use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation:"horizontal"`. You can customize how cells fill the available space using `android:layout_weight`, or set some to a fixed width you specify in `android:layout_width`. For cells you adjust using weights, `android:layout_width` should be set to `wrap_content`.

Then, here come the magic attributes:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:divider="@drawable/yourDividerDrawable"
    android:showDividers="middle"
/>
```

And that's it!

The `showDividers` property tells the LinearLayout to automatically draw dividers for you between items, using the drawable specified in the `divider` property.
Here, `showDividers` is set to `middle` so that dividers are drawn between items only. Other possible values enable adding separators before the first item or after the last one.

Answer (score 0):

list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="a" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="B" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="C" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="D" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.30"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="E" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="F" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="G" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="H" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple method that does not require you to alter your row layout,  is to wrap the listview within a FrameLayout.  In this case, I am placing 2 lines 100dp and 102 dp from the left margin.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

</FrameLayout>
```